# Jquery append only new data to object

Tags: php, jquery, twitter, feed

I'm trying to create a tweeter feed that updates every 30seconds.
I have the tweets coming in ok, but having trouble getting the feed to just add new tweets not all tweets again.

Pastebin of my code.
http://pastebin.com/YBsUyKaC

What i think i need to do is every time it re-checks the feed to only add any new tweets.

How would I get it to check if the tweet is already in the object and if it is dont add, if its not add.

thanks

Comment: Instead of checking if already exists and appending, why just use `.html()` with the data retrieved? It sounds like it has all the data you need.

Comment: hmmm, sounds like a good idea. care to explain a bit more? thanks

Comment: What is the total number of tweets you want show at one time?

Comment: I need it to just keep incrementing.

Comment: Actually maybe to a limit of 100. so it would count up to 100 the drop off any over 100+. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a counter `var k=0;`
That counter would count how many tweets have been added since the loading of the script. After every timeout in the jQuery.each() function the loop would be skipped k times (the first k tweets that were added) and that function would add only the last n-k tweets.
Kind of naive but I think it would do the job.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I've setup the counter but how do I skip a each loop to start at k? Also do you recommend doing it a better way?

Comment: Just initialize another variable `var i=0;` at the start of the display_tweets function and while i<k skip inner code execution.
There is a better way of doing it but you need tinker with the GetTweets::get_most_recent() method and that's a little harder to implement.